# Publ Math Debrecen 1949

Tags: reference-request

I am trying to find a paper (by Egervary) in Publ Math Debrecen, 1949 - I am having trouble finding an online version (the journal has an online presence but it does not go back that far). Any help much appreciated.

For Andras: Egevary (if I understand correctly) writes down a formula for the volume of the convex hull of (a class of) space curves, and uses it to prove an isoperimetric inequality.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the paper?

Comment: The universal answer for such questions: interlibrary loan.

Comment: E. Egervary: On the smallest convex cover of a simple arc of space-curve. Publicationes Mathematicae Debrecen, I (1949), 65-70. Here you can find  [a library near you](http://www.worldcat.org/title/publicationes-mathematicae-debrecen/oclc/610510003/editions?sd=asc&referer=di&se=yr&qt=facet_yr%3A&editionsView=true&fq=yr%3A1949) that has this volume. It has been scanned [by HathiTrust](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b3530130), but only limited search is available because of copyright restrictions.

Comment: @AndrásBátkai See the edit, thanks!

Comment: @AndyPutman Part of the reason I am asking is that this is not the first time I see a reference to PMD, and asking for interlibrary loan every time is annoying. I don't appreciate the condescension, however.

Comment: Since the owner of the copyright to the journal has not posted the older back issues online, any repository of scans of these issues would be of questionable legality.  For this reason, I think it would be inappropriate to have links to such sites here on MO.  Thus, obtaining the journal from the library (either in the usual way or by interlibrary loan) is in my opinion the only ethical suggestion to make here.

Comment: @AndyPutman The point of my question was to see if they had, in fact, made it available, just not in an easy to find way (their current issues are freely available, so it would be strange if the old ones were not, but strange things are the norm these days).